# How to give workers individual access to resources

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, service, authorization

I'm currently having one design problem that is:

I have a distributed system where I have a main "data service", that receives requests and handout the data, and some workers that are created using the same container image.

However, I want some these workers to have access to diferent data. The data service could just accept all requests and trust the workers, but as the workers may in the future have user code, I want a no-trust environment.

One way I though of doing is to assign a "random key" (private/public key, one-time password, token...) for each worker at it's creation, send this key to the data service and the data service would know which resources the worker would have access to.
I think that's not too dificult to create, but I wouldn't want to recreate the wheel, specialy something that deals with security.
Do you guys know any authentication/authorization method (Kerberos, SAML, OIDC, etc) that solves this problem?

BTW, we're using Keycloak for SSO and I think that it uses OIDC, but as far as I know it is password based and I have a hard time thinking if it could solve this problem.